# Multiple jenkins pipelines 1 docker-compose deployment

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, cd

I have project it needs 4 3rd party services
Mssql cache elastic kafka.
I have 15 apps and i want deploy all on single server using 1 single docker compose file.
Every service has its own jenkins pipeline which build application and publish on docker repository
My folder architecture look like this.

App1/jenkinsfile

App2/jenkinsfile

App15/jenkinsfile

......

Thirdparty/jenkinsfile

Dockercompose.yaml

I need to deploy every service in order. Like app1 app2....app15 through jenkins pipeline.

I am using multi branch pipeline if changes made to any application jenkins will run all pipeline (app1 to app15) did not deploy in order.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to deployee this service in order app1 app2 app3 so on